# ASP.NET 4.0 WebForms URL Rewrite breaks MS Chart

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, url-rewriting, charts

I've added the new Chart control to my project and it works well. I've set the

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=memory;timeout=20;" />

<handlers>
  <add name="ChartImg" verb="*" path="ChartImg.axd"  type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"  />
</handlers>
```

Everything is fine as long as I use the "/host/Poll.aspx" path in my browser. Things break when switching over to the rewritten URL "host/poll/". I am getting the **"System.Web.HttpException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Error executing child request for ChartImg.axd."** exception.

Any ideas how to fix it? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cant actually try this at the moment but how about "~/ChartImg.axd"

Failing that try using image locations

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="Storage=file; Timeout=20; Url=~/Temp/Charting/;"/>
```

**Edit:** And update your chart html

```
<asp:Chart ID="chrt1" runat="server" Width="550px" Height="400px" 
    SuppressExceptions="True" ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation"
    ImageLocation="~/Temp/Charting/ChartPic_#SEQ(1000,30)">
```

And make sure the directory you are writing to exists. I normally do this on app start in the global

Comment: Unfortunately none of these two seem to work. Still getting the same error :(

Comment: Can you post your actual chart html?

Comment: You mean the URL? The actual aspx file is in the root directory named "Poll.aspx". The folder for the images is "~/img/charts/". Route is set to "/poll/"

Comment: This works! Setting the StorageMode to ImageLocation works. I am worried though, does this generate a picture for every user that views the page? That sounds scary.

Comment: No. #SEQ(maxFiles,minutes) - Generates a sequence number that ranges from 1 up to maxFiles, before restarting back at 1. This ensures that there are never more than maxFiles number of chart image files stored in the specified folder. The minutes parameter specifies the number of minutes old a file must be before the file name can be reused.

Answer (score 3):

in case you upgrade your website from .Net 3.0 to .Net 4.0 and using IIS 7 you must insert some line in your webconfig like here :

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ChartImageHandler"/>
            <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```